# Location services in iOS5.1 not working as it should

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager

I have a simply app written in Objective-C that gets my current position using `CLLocationManager`, etc. The code works fine on the iPhone 6.1 Simulator, but it doesn't work on my actual iPod touch. The iPod Touch 3rd Gen is running iOS5.1, and it does ask for the user to enable location services, however it does not get updated. I can post code if you ask, but I thought that there would just be a glaring compatibility issue that would be a rather simple fix. 
Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks!
~Carpetfizz

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate>
{
    CLLocationManager* locationManager;
}

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *labelLong;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *labelLat;
-(IBAction)updateLocaitonButtonAction:(id)sender;
@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize labelLong,labelLat;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    CLLocation *location = [locations lastObject];
    NSLog(@"%f,%f",location.coordinate.latitude,location.coordinate.longitude);
    self.labelLong.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",location.coordinate.longitude];
    self.labelLat.text  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",location.coordinate.latitude];
    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
}

-(IBAction)updateLocaitonButtonAction:(id)sender
{
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: Does the standard maps app know where you are? The iPod touch locates based on WiFi signals so isn't terribly accurate.

Comment: It gets the right street actually. Is that why I can't get the latitude and longitude? Even if its slightly off, I think I should still get a number. Thoughts ?

Comment: Interestingly, the Twitter app, which uses Location services gets my location precisely.

Comment: If you can get a location from the maps app then you should be able to get a coordinate from location manager.  Can't think of any compatibility issues off the top of my head - maybe something to do with filtering?

Comment: @LewisGordon iirc, I set all filtering to none. I'll post some code, hopefully it'll make it easier to understand.    `locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use this delegate

```
 - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
      CLLocation *location = newLocation;
      NSLog(@"%f,%f",location.coordinate.latitude,location.coordinate.longitude);
}
```

Comment: didUpdateLocations is new to iOS6 so that would be why it didn't work on an iOS5 device.